# Two scrollbars after adding scroll affect in css and svelte

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, svelte

I was following this tut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htw4iKMYzEc by dev ed but I get two scrollbars, even when I added `height: 100vh;` which fixed it for him. Here's the code and thanks for any help!

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="one">
        <Sort />
    </section>
    <section class="two">
        <Todo />
    </section>
</div>

<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    section {
        height: 100vh;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }

    .container {
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it overflowed the body which has a padding by default, to fix it you need to remove the body padding first:

```
<style>
    :global(body) {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Everything inside the component is scoped so you have to use `global` to access other dom targets